# Excluding items from a list in coldfusion by type

Tags: coldfusion, file-type

Is there a way to exclude certain items by filetype in a list in Coldfusion?
Background: I just integrated a compression tool into an existing application and ran into the problem of the person's prior code would automatically grab the file from the upload destination on the server and push it to the Network Attached Storage. The aim now is to stop their NAS migration code from moving all files to the NAS, only those which are not PDF's. What I want to do is loop through their variable that stores the names of the files uploaded, and exclude the pdf's from the list then pass the list onto the NAS code, so all non pdf's are moved and all pdf's uploaded remain on the server. Working with their code is a challenge as no one commented or documented anything and I've been trying several approaches.

```
    <cffile action="upload" destination= "c:\uploads\" result="myfiles" nameconflict="makeunique" >

    <cfset fileSys = CreateObject('component','cfc.FileManagement')>

    <cfif Len(get.realec_transactionid)>
        <cfset internalOnly=1 >
    </cfif>     
    **This line below is what I want to loop through and exclude file names 
    with pdf extensions **
    <cfset uploadedfilenames='#myfiles.clientFile#' >

    <CFSET a_insert_time = #TimeFormat(Now(), "HH:mm:ss")#>
    <CFSET a_insert_date = #DateFormat(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy")#>
    **This line calls their method from another cfc that has all the file 
    migration methods.**
    <cfset new_file_name = #fileSys.MoveFromUploads(uploadedfilenames)#>
    **Once it moves the file to the NAS, it inserts the file info into the 
    DB table here**
    <cfquery name="addFile" datasource="#request.dsn#">
        INSERT INTO upload_many (title_id, fileDate, filetime, fileupload)
                VALUES('#get.title_id#', '#dateTimeStamp#', '#a_insert_time#', '#new_file_name#')
    </cfquery>


<cfelse>    
    <cffile action="upload" destination= #ExpandPath("./uploaded_files/zip.txt")# nameconflict="overwrite" >
</cfif>
```

**Update 6/18** 
Trying the recommended code helps with the issue of sorting out filetypes when tested outside of the application, but anytime its integrated into the application to operate on the variable `uploadedfilenames` the rest of the application fails and the multi-file upload module just throws a status 500 error and no errors are reported in the CF logs. I've found that simply trying to run a `cfloop` on another variable not related to anything in the code still causes it to error.

Comment: Which version of CF are you on? Also, if your question is "how do I take this list and remove some things from it on this basis", can you provide us with a repro case that actually just focuses on that, rather than all that other irrelevant bumpf you've posted? Give us a hard-coded list of input data, detail the omission criteria, and show us the desired end result. And detail what you've tried and how it didn't work too, would be helpful.

Comment: You would want to re-phrase the question a little bit to "Excluding items from a list of files in coldfusion by it's file type (extension)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to filter-out file names with a specific file type/extension (ex: pdf) from the main list `uploadedfilenames`. This is one of the easiest ways:

```
<cfset lFileNames = "C:\myfiles\proj\icon-img-12.png,C:\myfiles\proj\sample-file.ppt,C:\myfiles\proj\fin-doc1.docx,C:\myfiles\proj\fin-doc2.pdf,C:\myfiles\proj\invoice-temp.docx,C:\myfiles\proj\invoice-final.pdf" />
<cfset lResultList = "" />
<cfset fileExtToExclude = "pdf" />
<cfloop list="#lFileNames#" index="fileItem" delimiters=",">
<cfif ListLast(ListLast(fileItem,'\'),'.') NEQ fileExtToExclude>
    <cfset lResultList = ListAppend(lResultList,"#fileItem#") />
</cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Using only List Function provided by ColdFusion this is easily done, you can test and try the code [here](http://trycf.com/gist/5c726ca8c851a4ea072f/acf11?theme=monokai). I would recommend you to wrap this code around a function for easy handling. Another way to do it would be to use some complex regular expression on the list (if you're looking for a more general solution, outside the context of ColdFusion).

Now, applying the solution to your problem:

```
<cfset uploadedfilenames='#myfiles.clientFile#' >
<cfset lResultList = "" />
<cfset fileExtToExclude = "pdf" />
<cfloop list="#uploadedfilenames#" index="fileItem" delimiters=",">
  <cfif ListLast(ListLast(fileItem,'\'),'.') NEQ fileExtToExclude>
      <cfset lResultList = ListAppend(lResultList,fileItem) />
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfset uploadedfilenames = lResultList />
<!--- rest of your code continues --->
```

The result list `lResultList` is copied to the original variable `uploadedfilenames`.

Comment: No doubt that this approach works when tested on a different list, but for some reason, every method I've tried to resolve this problem just causes the multiple file upload module to kickback a Status 500 Error code and the CF logs aren't logging any errors on this portion of the application.

Comment: You said you tried some method already, and it caused an error, shouldn't  that be in your question originally. Your question did not mention any issues with the multiple file upload module or any methods you have already tried. Now will be a good time to update your question to reflect what is the issue you're facing and what you want. As per your question of excluding files based on types, I think this is what you wanted.

Comment: Please mark it as accepted if it answers your question. I see you already raised another question for the [Multiple file upload module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924500/coldfusion-9-flash-multifile-upload-widget-fails-due-to-unrelated-code) which is a good move as it was a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding the question, but why don't you just wrap all of that in an if-statement that reads the full file name? Whether the files are coming one by one or through a delimited list, it should be easy to work around.

`<cfif !listContains(ListName, '.pdf')>`

OR

`<cfif FileName does not contain '.pdf'>`

then

`all the code you posted`